# using tikz to plot a matrix as a heatmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

How can I plot a matrix of density distributions like this ?

```
A=
    0.0333    0.0333    0.9000    0.9000
    0.9000    0.0333    0.0333    0.0333
    0.0333    0.9000    0.0333    0.0333
    0.0333    0.0333    0.0333    0.0333;
```

I would like to plot above matrix (for instance) with `pgfplots` or `tikz` as a bilinear interpolation heat map or an image in gray scale. How can I do it?

**Update**
From example on the web I made this:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{filecontents*}{temp.dat}
0 0 0.0333            
1 0 0.0333             
2 0 0.9000            
3 0 0.9000            

0 1 0.9000
1 1 0.0333
2 1 0.0333
3 1 0.0333

0 2 0.0333
1 2 0.9000
2 2 0.0333
3 2 0.0333

0 3 0.0333
1 3 0.0333
2 3 0.0333
3 3 0.0333
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},   % not needed for `matrix plot*' variant
            xlabel=context,
            ylabel=outcome,
            colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)},
            colorbar,
            colorbar style={
                title=$ $,
                yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    fixed,
                    precision=1,
                    fixed zerofill,
                },
            },
            title=$\mathbf{A}_{\mathrm{dom}}$,
            %
            % added these key-values
            enlargelimits=false,
            axis on top,
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=1,
            %
            % uncomment me to show, that there are really no cells plotted
            % when using the second variant (`surf, shader=flat corner')
            %xmax=5,
            %ymax=5,
        ]
            %% gives the mean temperature of the neighbouring cells (4x4 matrix)
            %\addplot3 [surf] file {temp.dat};

            %% gives the temperature of each point where the reference point
            %% is the lower left corner of the cell (also a 4x4 matrix)
            %% (I already asked the package author if this is intended or a bug)
            %\addplot3 [surf,shader=flat corner] file {temp.dat};

            % this should give the desired output (5x5 matrix)
            \addplot [matrix plot*,point meta=explicit] file [meta=index 2] {temp.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Problems with this figure

1. It seems it got rotated. How can I fix it?
2. Is there anyway to put xticklabels and yticklabels for the figure such as text instead of numbers?
3. how can I remove the colorbar? I tried to comment out the line and I got errors.
4. How could I use a similar structure of matrix as I posted earlier use to build this plot instead of breaking it down like examples?
   Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at section **4.6.12 Image (Matrix) Plots** of the pgfplots manual?

Comment: @user238301 no I have not.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can invert the direction of the y axis with `y dir = reverse` in the options of the `axis` environment.
2. Manually you can control the tick labels with the `xtick`/`ytick` and `xticklabels`/`yticklabels` keys in the options of the `axis` environment. E.g.

   ```
   xtick = {0,1,2,3},
   ytick = {0,1,2,3},
   xticklabels = {
       $x_0$,
       $x_1$,
       $x_2$,
       $x_3$
   },
   yticklabels = {
       $y_0$,
       $y_1$,
       $y_2$,
       $y_3$
   },
   ```
3. The color bar is controlled by the `colorbar` key. Set `colorbar = false` or just comment out `colorbar`.